# Unity3D Linux Build crashes on start. (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I am struggling in making Unity3D Build working in Ubuntu Linux Environment. 
I just created an empty scene without any objects build a linux distribution, but it crashes in linux and giving following error.

```
'/home/jayanth/Desktop/EmptyLinuxTest/Empty_Linux.x86' 
Found path: /home/jayanth/Desktop/EmptyLinuxTest/Empty_Linux.x86
Mono path[0] ='/home/jayanth/Desktop/EmptyLinuxTest/Empty_Linux_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/home/jayanth/Desktop/EmptyLinuxTest/Empty_Linux_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/home/jayanth/Desktop/EmptyLinuxTest/Empty_Linux_Data/Mono/etc'
displaymanager : xrandr version warning. 1.5
client has 2 screens
displaymanager screen (0)(VGA-0): 1368 x 768
Using libudev for joystick management


Importing game controller configs
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the Player.log file output.

```
Selecting FBConfig
GLX_FBCONFIG_ID=227
GLX_BUFFER_SIZE=32
GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER=1
GLX_RED_SIZE=8
GLX_GREEN_SIZE=8
GLX_BLUE_SIZE=8
GLX_ALPHA_SIZE=8
GLX_DEPTH_SIZE=24
GLX_STENCIL_SIZE=8
GLX_SAMPLES_ARB=0
GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB=0
GLX_STEREO=0
GLX_CONFIG_CAVEAT=NONE

Desktop is 1368 x 768 @ 60 Hz
XError: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) (error 8, opcode 154/34, serial 37, XID 00000004, display 0xa96bdf0
XError: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) (error 8, opcode 154/34, serial 40, XID 00000004, display 0xa96bdf0
XError: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) (error 8, opcode 154/34, serial 43, XID 00000004, displaterminate called after throwing an instance of    'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

Stacktrace:

```
Native stacktrace:

/home/jayanth/Desktop/EmptyLinuxTest/Empty_Linux_Data/Mono/x86/libmono.so(+0x8960f) [0xb4da760f]
[0xb775cc20]
[0xb775cc31]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39) [0xb7160e89]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x157) [0xb71623e7]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x155) [0xb73cfd45]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x70843) [0xb73cd843]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x708bd) [0xb73cd8bd]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(__cxa_rethrow+0) [0xb73cdb80]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt19__throw_logic_errorPKc+0x44) [0xb73f78b4]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x8b66b48]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x8b5802e]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x8b4a2ba]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x8b568c9]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x8adb803]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x8ad81f7]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x82ce6bf]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x83efceb]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x83c6c12]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x808e473]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf7) [0xb714d637]
./Empty_Linux.x86() [0x80988e9]
```

Debug info from gdb:

```
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No threads.

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

It would be glad if someone help me out in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: you're using a joystick or similar ??

Comment: No, I am NOT using any joystick. Same build if I am making for Windows/Mac its working perfectly fine, but NOT sure why it is creating problem in Linux

Comment: Same issue here @Niks, did you happen to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The line "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid" in your logs suggests that Unity3d is trying to construct a std::string object from a null pointer which is undefined behaviour according to the C++ standard & current libstdc++ versions throw a std::logic_error exception if your code tries to do that.

This may well be a bug in Unity itself - there are a few complaints about similar errors dotted around if you search the net.

Comment: Well, just for random test, I installed a nVidia Graphics card in my system and then it started working in linux but still it was damn slow. I can't conclude on anything as the same is working in windows without graphics card and in the same system. So, I think Unity is still NOT completely ready for Linux (May be) ...